# Turkish airlines new fares. Is 'Economy Promotion' modifiable?

Tags: fares, turkish-airlines, fare-class

Several days ago, I visited the new web site of Turkish airlines and see some interesting fares. However, I can't figure out whether the cheapest fare ticket can be be modified or not.

I'm not pressed for time, so I'll ask this question here before trying to call Turkey and try to explain my question.

So, let's take for example a flight from Paris to Tokyo:

[image]

Selecting the first flight, I open fare conditions and see that 'Economy promotion' is neither modifiable nor reimbursable. That's to be expected.

[image]

I select the return flight and see the same fare conditions

[image]

I confirm it and see the price

[image]

After I go a bit above and see selected fare conditions

[image]

No surprise. Let's do it for return flight

[image]

And here's what we see. This one is still not reimbursable but modifiable with a fee. Is it some issue at their new web site or can this one really be modifiable?

The same things happens for other destinations and dates. If I go to the old version of site, I see that the same flights for this price cannot be changed. 
Has anybody had experience with this happening to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are most likely several different fare buckets that fall into Turkish Airlines' "Economy Promotion" category.  Each of these fare buckets could have a different base price (as maybe demonstrated in your first example) and could have different change / re-issue rules (as shown in your second example).

Airlines don't really show you what fare bucket you are in during the early stages on booking, so it leads to much price confusion by inexperienced travelers.  If you take time to view the fare rules themselves for your flight examples, you will likely see that each flight suggestion has a different fare basis (a 5 to 8 character code, usually starting with a letter). The first letter is usually the fare bucket.

Comment: Many non-refundable fares are changeable, unless they have a specific rule for non-changeable.  And even those can sometimes be changed with full service airlines under the right conditions and speaking with the right agent.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to an Tom's answer I started again to check there site and found there fare rules here https://p.turkishairlines.com/en-fr/any-questions/fare-rules/index.html

[image]

It seems that their 'Economy promotion' fare can be modifiable. I proceeded to the payment page, as it is shown in their documentation, and they showed me that ticket can be modified (the same conditions like at my screenshots when 'I went up')